# Facebook Graph API JSON email

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the web Graph API to get data from facebook. 
I need to get the email of the user.

I have a function to get and parse JSON data. I use it with the access token to get what I want but I can only get name and ID.

This is my Facebook permissions

```
fbButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
```

But, when I print my array from the json I have only

```
{
  "name" : "**********",
  "id" : "************"
}
```

If i use the Facebook Graph API Explorer and I create a Token, I can reach all data about me. But impossible when I create my token in swift.

I have also validate my facebook app and email data is activated.

Did somebody have any idea to help me?

====

Edit 1

This is how I call the graph API

```
// Facebook Delegate Methods
func loginButton(connection: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {

    if (error != nil)
    {
        println("Error")
    }
    else {
        // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
        // should check if specific permissions missing
        if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email")
        {
            // Do work
        }
        println("User logged in")
        performSegueWithIdentifier("Login", sender: self)
    }
}
```

And here when I instantiate the fb login button

```
if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() == nil)
    {
        // User is not already logged
        println("No Logged")
        loading.hidden = true
        fbButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
        fbButton.delegate = self
    }
    else
    {
        fbButton.hidden = true
        println("Already Logged")
        performSegueWithIdentifier("Login", sender: self)
        println(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().permissions)
        parseJSON(getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/me/?access_token=" + FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString))
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly say which results you want from the query. In your case it should be something like the following:

```
me?fields=id,name,email
```

===

**EXTRA**: I will suggest that you make use of the built in class `FBSDKGraphRequest` from the Facebook SDK. You could do something like the following:

```
if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil {
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me?fields=id,name,email,gender,first_name,last_name,middle_name,birthday", parameters: nil).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) in

        // Something went wrong
        if (error != nil) {
            errorHandler()
            return
        }

        // Parses the returned result
        if let userData = result as? NSDictionary {

            // Extracts the  data points
            let fbId = userData[FacebookGraphConstants.Id] as? String ?? ""
            let gender = userData[FacebookGraphConstants.Gender] as? String ?? ""
            let birthdayString = userData[FacebookGraphConstants.Birthday] as? String ?? ""
            let email = userData[FacebookGraphConstants.Email] as? String ?? ""
            let firstName = userData[FacebookGraphConstants.FirstName] as? String ?? ""
            let middleName = userData[FacebookGraphConstants.MiddleName] as? String ?? ""
            let lastName = userData[FacebookGraphConstants.LastName] as? String ?? ""
            let displayName = userData[FacebookGraphConstants.DisplayName] as? String ?? ""
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but you did not answered the question :S
I have a link like this : https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=myToken and it's works nice with my token from Graph Explorer
And I've used the FBSDKGraphRequest but I have many troubles with async function ....

Comment: Could you please provide some more code regarding how you are calling the graph api it in the app?

Answer (score 0):

I just solve my problem by adding this in my URL :

```
/me?fields=email&access_token=....
```

I put Kumuluzz answer in usefull, thank you :)